# Kubernetes. Is it possible to mount volume to path containing pod id?

Tags: kubernetes, deployment, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-pvc

I want to define pvc and create volume in order to get some internal files from container outside (I am using helm charts definitions). I want to know is there any way to use POD IP in mountPath that I am defining in deployment.yaml.

At the end I want to get folder structure in my node
/dockerdata-nfs//path

```
volumeMounts:
     - name: volumeName
       mountPath: /abc/path

volumes:
    - name: volumeName
      hostPath:
        path: /dockerdata-nfs/podID/
```

Comment: You wrote `POD IP` and `podID` and now I am not sure what do you want to do exactly. Second thing is that you wrote `... use POD IP in mountPath ...`, but when I look at the part of a deployment you provided there is `podID` (assuming these refer to the same thing but you misspelled something) but its under hostPath.path. Can you edit your question to be unambiguous?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> POD on recreation will get a new UID so why will you try to hard code this value !!

[Pods](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod/#what-is-a-pod) are considered to be relatively ephemeral (rather than durable) entities. As discussed in pod lifecycle, Pods are created, assigned a unique ID (UID), and scheduled to nodes where they remain until termination (according to restart policy) or deletion. If a Node dies, the Pods scheduled to that node are scheduled for deletion, after a timeout period. A given Pod (as defined by a UID) is not “rescheduled” to a new node; instead, it can be replaced by an identical Pod, with even the same name if desired, **but with a new UID** (see replication controller for more details).

Comment: My main aim is to extract some files from pod to some folder at host machine. However I need somehow to separate files between pods. For example I have 2 replicas of my pod, I want to get files (with the same names) to different locations. 
I didn't want to hardcode the podID, I just asking if there is an option to put some variable that will be resolved while deploying.

Comment: then you should share the volume using subPath where you can map subPath value to your container name which i believe will be static anyday.

Comment: but container name is the same for each of the replica no?

Comment: right .. can you make your question more clear on that you are working with replicationset/deployment ..

Comment: it is deployment

Comment: I believe use of StefulSet is better solution for your use case and not a deployment.

Comment: It is not an option. \is there any other way?

Comment: I am afraid not in my view .. where you are trying to achieve statefull kind of requirement using deployments .. **StatefulSets are the recommended method of deploying stateful applications that require a unique volume per replica**. By using StatefulSets with Persistent Volume Claim Templates you can have applications that can scale up automatically with unique Persistent Volume Claims associated to each replica Pod.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a mountPath based on the POD UID using the `subPathExpr`. Yaml below:

`apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: pod1
spec:
  containers:
  - name: container1
    env:
    - name: UID
      valueFrom:
        fieldRef:
          apiVersion: v1
          fieldPath: metadata.uid
    image: busybox
    volumeMounts:
    - name: workdir1
      mountPath: /logs
      subPathExpr: $(UID)
  volumes:
  - name: workdir1
    hostPath:
      path: /var/log/pods`

This feature was introduced in Kubernetes version 1.14+.